# Crawl HTML data from an EngineSession

Tags: android, mozilla, geckoview

In my Android app, I use an [EngineSession](https://github.com/mozilla-mobile/android-components/blob/main/components/concept/engine/src/main/java/mozilla/components/concept/engine/EngineSession.kt) (rendered by an [EngineView](https://github.com/mozilla-mobile/android-components/blob/main/components/concept/engine/src/main/java/mozilla/components/concept/engine/EngineView.kt)) to display data. In actual fact, this data is plain JSON. Is there a way I can crawl/scrape the HTML directly from the EngineSession so that I can have access to the JSON being returned?

If I was using a WebView, I could have used WebView's `evaluateJavascript()` function.

The only EngineSession functions I can see that can potentially export the HTML data are:

- requestPdfToDownload()
- requestPrintContent()

But neither of these functions gives direct access to the raw HTML being displayed. How can I go about this?

I would appreciate any help or pointers.

Comment: You can inject JavaScript into a web page using the command **EngineSession.executeJavaScript()**

Comment: @IvanAbakumov, I can't find this function in the EngineSession class (dependency version 118.2.0). Can you kindly give more context?

Answer (score 1):

I did some research. then `webview` deployment was noticed in the following situation.

It is loaded into the [relevant webView](https://github.com/woojiahao/android-components/blob/eb9efef5e89624f3373c3d98f61f72fffb950dbe/components/browser/engine-system/src/main/java/mozilla/components/browser/engine/system/SystemEngineView.kt#L76).

```
override fun render(session: EngineSession) {
        val internalSession = session as SystemEngineSession
        this.session = internalSession

        internalSession.view = WeakReference(this)
        internalSession.initSettings()

        internalSession.scheduledLoad.data?.let {
             // it -> string html
            currentWebView.loadData(it, internalSession.scheduledLoad.mimeType, "UTF-8")
            internalSession.scheduledLoad = ScheduledLoad()
        }

        internalSession.scheduledLoad.url?.let {
            currentWebView.loadUrl(it, additionalHeaders)
            internalSession.scheduledLoad = ScheduledLoad()
        }
    }
```

If you can access the `engineSession`. you can use

```
val internalSession = session as SystemEngineSession
var data = internalSession.scheduledLoad.data
```

Comment: Thanks for your attempt, but this question is not about SystemEngineSession. It's a reference to Mozilla's AndroidComponent EngineSession (it's hyperlinked in the question). My project is not built to reference SystemEngineSession. Or am I misinterpreting your answer?

Comment: If you can provide a reference, you can access the relevant data.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can you kindly hint me on what dependency to include in my gradle file to be able to get SystemEngineSession reference?

Comment: you can review : https://github.com/gaul/android-components/blob/fbadb244114d5d99cb99a521c2404ac259ceb0e3/components/browser/engine-system/README.md

Comment: Thanks. Two things:

1. The scheduledLoad function does not exist (or is not public).
2. Eventually got a ClassCastException: mozilla.components.browser.engine.gecko.GeckoEngineSession cannot be cast to mozilla.components.browser.engine.system.SystemEngineSession.